# Save listbox items as child items in xml file using linq and c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a relatively simple Winforms application and am using C#.  I have been using LINQ (system.xml.linq) ... I have successfully been saving textbox items (single items) to my xml file.

I have a listBox of items and would like that list to be saved as child nodes in the xml file.  So my xml final output would look something like this:

```
<items>
 <centerName>My Center</centerName>
 <poc>Mr. Jones</poc>
 <servicedUnits>
    <state>Texas</state>
    <state>Iowa</state>
    <state>Hawaii</state>
 </servicedUnits>
</items>
```

I have this code that I have been using to write to XML:

```
    private void writeFCATSettings()
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument
        (
            new XElement
              ("Items",
                new XElement("textBoxCenterName", textBoxCenterName.Text),
                new XElement("textBoxContactFirstName", textBoxContactFirstName.Text),   

                new XElement("servicedUnits", "<listBoxServicedUnits.Items>")

              )
          );
        doc.Save(@"Settings.xml");
    }
```

I am pretty sure I need to put code to iterate through the listbox between the brackets .

And lastly..I found this code that does iterate through my list...but if I just paste it into the space  ... it doesn't work.

```
XElement servicedUnits = new XElement("ServicedUnits");
        foreach (var item in listBoxServicedUnits.Items)
        {
            servicedUnits.Add(new XElement("unit", item));
        }

        XDocument document = new XDocument();
        document.Add(servicedUnits);
```

Thank you for any ideas...

ER

Comment: What do you have in `listBoxServicedUnits.Items`? strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your listbox's items are strings you could do this:

```
private void writeFCATSettings()
{
    XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XElement("Items",
            new XElement("textBoxCenterName", textBoxCenterName.Text),
            new XElement("textBoxContactFirstName", textBoxContactFirstName.Text),   
            new XElement("servicedUnits", 
                listBoxServicedUnits
                .Items
                .OfType<string>()
                .Select(item => new XElement("unit", item)))));
    doc.Save(@"Settings.xml");
}
```

Or, if they are not strings or they are mixed types you could do this:

```
private void writeFCATSettings()
{
    XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XElement("Items",
            new XElement("textBoxCenterName", textBoxCenterName.Text),
            new XElement("textBoxContactFirstName", textBoxContactFirstName.Text),   
            new XElement("servicedUnits", 
                listBoxServicedUnits
                .Items
                .OfType<Object>()
                .Select(x => TransformYouObjectToAStringHere)
                .Select(item => new XElement("unit", item)))));
    doc.Save(@"Settings.xml");
}
```

Comment: I get the following error: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Oh right, `ItemCollection` only inherits `IEnumerable` not `IEnumerable<T>`.  I will update the answer shortly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help...I apologize for my lack of coding skill...but I'm not sure what needs to happen in your solution where you have "TransformYouObjectToAStringHere" ...

Comment: You are going to want to replace that with some function that can take whatever type `x` is and create a `String`.  The most obvious example being `x.ToString()`.  What type of objects are the listbox's items?

Comment: Great thank you ... the listbox items are text strings...it works great.  Thank you for your help.